# php dont return the config file content

Tags: php, include, filepath

```
public function loadConfig($config)
{
    if(is_file(path('config') . $config . '.php'))
    {
        return include_once path('config') . $config . '.php';
    }

}
```

I have the same function for loading models in the controller and everything is ok. But I cant include the config file, the path is right. If I put before the return

```
include_once path('config') . $config . '.php';
print_r($config_array);
```

It print the array value

Comment: `include_once` does not make any sense here, you will want to load the file every time the method is invoked. Also, does the included file contain `return $config_array;`?

Comment: I want to load the config file in the controller. And yes the include file contain $config_array.

Comment: This loader have to be similar to Codeigniter config loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to strip the "_once" (because preventing a second inclusion does not make sense in this context, it does for classes but not for config files). Furthermore, you need to either include a "return" statement in the included file or return the array, not the return value of the include function:

```
public function loadConfig($config)
{
    $filename = path('config') . $config . '.php';
    if (is_readable($filename)) {
        include($filename);
        return $config_array;
    }

    // error handling, i.e., throw an exception ...
}
```

---

Solution using the "return" statement:

Config file:

```
$config_array = array( ... );
return $config_array;
```

Class with the config loader method:

```
public function loadConfig($config)
{
    $filename = path('config') . $config . '.php';
    if (is_readable($filename)) {
        return include($filename);
    }

    // error handling, i.e., throw an exception ...
}
```

Comment: Still is dosent work, but if i put echo 'include ?'; in the config file, when open the controller i see the text but i cant access the config array from the controller.